# wrong result for $\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I have some problem with the result of this integral:

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\sqrt{x}}dx$$

The result should be `2` but I get `-2` but I do not see the error, can someone please show me where is it?

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{k} e^{-\sqrt{x}} dx$$

let

$$-\sqrt{x} = t$$

so:

$$ dx = 2t $$

Calculate the indefinite integral:

$$ \int e^{-\sqrt{x}} dx = 2\int te^t dt$$

Solve by parts:

$$2\int te^t dt = 2te^t - 2e^t$$

Get back in `x`:

$$2te^t - 2e^t = -2\sqrt{x}e^{-\sqrt{x}} - 2e^{-\sqrt{x}}$$

So:

$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \big[ -2\sqrt{x}e^{-\sqrt{x}} - 2e^{-\sqrt{x}} \big]_{0}^{k} = -2$$

Comment: In general, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{\large-\sqrt[n]x}~dx~=~n!$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that when substituting the limits the only non-vanishing term comes from the lower limit ($x=0$) and hence changes sign.

Comment: Yeah, thanks...just a stupid error!